# Import "torch" could not be resolved

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytorch

Using vscode 1.60.2

Running this code in command line, after executing the "python" command works.  So I know that the library is properly installed.  This is a problem specifically with vscode.  I restarted vscode, and even restarted windows after installing pytorch with pip.  Did not fix it.

```
import torch

# Model
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s', pretrained=True)

# Images
imgs = ['https://ultralytics.com/images/zidane.jpg']  # batch of images

# Inference
results = model(imgs)

# Results
results.print()
results.save()  # or .show()

results.xyxy[0]  # img1 predictions (tensor)
results.pandas().xyxy[0]  # img1 predictions (pandas)
#      xmin    ymin    xmax   ymax  confidence  class    name
# 0  749.50   43.50  1148.0  704.5    0.874023      0  person
# 1  433.50  433.50   517.5  714.5    0.687988     27     tie
# 2  114.75  195.75  1095.0  708.0    0.624512      0  person
# 3  986.00  304.00  1028.0  420.0    0.286865     27     tie
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have changed which interpreter you're using for Python.  In VSCode go to the command palette and search for `Python: Select Interpreter`.  If there's a default option go with that since that's where you might have installed the module to using pip.  Should look something like this.  Command palette can be reached by `Ctrl+Shift+p`.  If that doesn't work set up a virtual environment for your project and install your module there.

[image]

Comment: Yeah this worked.  The "recommended" interpreter was causing the problem, switched to the other selection and it fixed it.  Thanks, I will mark as answer when the option is available.